# Sharepoint 2010 multilingual support and SQL Server 2008 Collation

Tags: 2010, sql-server

I am wondering when I install my respective SQL Server 2008 R2 database for Sharepoint if I will need to set the collation to anything specific to support Sharepoint's multilingual capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

No, in fact, you should not adjust the SharePoint database collation settings at all.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2008668